# Change sildes automatically

Tags: javascript, slider

I have an JavaScript code for a full with silder with arrows. However, this JavaScript code is not making the slides change automatically. Can anybody help me with upgradeing this JS code, so the divs change automatically, after few seconds.

JavaScript code:

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left"),
arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right"),
current = 0;

// Clear all images
function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Initialize slider
function startSlide() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
}

// Show previous slide
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
  current--;
}

// Show next slide
function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
  current++;
}

// Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = sliderImages.length;
  }
  slideLeft();
});

// Right arrow click
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
});

startSlide();
```

HTML code:
(I only have two slides)

```
<div class="wrap">
  <!-- slider arrow -->
  <div class="arrow" id="arrow-left">
    <img class="zoom" src="images/icon_arrow_left.png" alt="arrow-left">
  </div> <!-- end slider arrow -->

  <div id="slider">
    <div class="slide slide1">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <h2>WELCOME TO EMS STUDIO</h2>
        <p class="italic">Together we lift your training to the new 
levels</p>
        <button class="slider-btn"><a href="">Read More</a></button> <!-- 
slider button -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide2">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <h2>EMS TRAINING FROM xBODY</h2>
        <p class="italic">Get your dream body with 30 minutes of exercise, 
only twice a week!</p>
        <button class="slider-btn"><a href="">Read More</a></button> <!-- 
slider button -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- slider arrow -->
  <div class="arrow" id="arrow-right">
    <img class="zoom" src="images/icon_arrow_right.png" alt="arrow-right">
  </div> <!-- end slider arrow -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/slider.js"></script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left"),
arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right"),
current = 0;

// Clear all images
function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Initialize slider
function startSlide() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
}

// Show previous slide
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
  current--;
}

// Show next slide
function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
  current++;
}

// Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = sliderImages.length;
  }
  slideLeft();
});

// Right arrow click
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
});
// Interval for slider
var a = function(){
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
}
setInterval(a, 2000);

startSlide();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrap">
  <!-- slider arrow -->
  <div class="arrow" id="arrow-left">
    <img class="zoom" src="images/icon_arrow_left.png" alt="arrow-left">
  </div> <!-- end slider arrow -->

  <div id="slider">
    <div class="slide slide1">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <h2>WELCOME TO EMS STUDIO</h2>
        <p class="italic">Together we lift your training to the new 
levels</p>
        <button class="slider-btn"><a href="">Read More</a></button> <!-- 
slider button -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide2">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <h2>EMS TRAINING FROM xBODY</h2>
        <p class="italic">Get your dream body with 30 minutes of exercise, 
only twice a week!</p>
        <button class="slider-btn"><a href="">Read More</a></button> <!-- 
slider button -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- slider arrow -->
  <div class="arrow" id="arrow-right">
    <img class="zoom" src="images/icon_arrow_right.png" alt="arrow-right">
  </div> <!-- end slider arrow -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I added at the end of your script with comment.

Comment: Thank you!! I actually tried the same, and it is working on the pc/mac, but not on the mobile devices. When I test it on my phone through the wamp server, it is not working. Do upu know maybe why?

Comment: It doesn't matter what device you use, it must work. Either there is an error in your code or you are using some other library which is conflicting with your current slider.